# Recommendation on how to store an event period

Tags: oop, data-structures

OK, let's say I am writing a calendar application in which a user can create an event. An event can occur in the following situations:

```
    1 time only. 
    Every Period of time keep reply, until a day.
    Every Period of time keep reply, until a day, except some days.
    Every some kind of week day.
```

Let me explain in a detailed example:

```
    1 time only: 24/8/2011 ONLY. 
    Every Period of time keep reply, until a day: 25/8/2011 Start, and every week end will have this event, until 30/10/2011.
    Every Period of time keep reply, until a day, except some days: 25/8/2011 Start, and every week end will have this event, until 30/10/2011, except the 10/09/2011 and 17/09/2011.
    Every some kind of week day, .
    Every some kind of week day, except some days.
```

Comment: Okay, so, what would you like us to do?

Answer (score 2):

Martin Fowler wrote a nice big article about just this topic a few years ago. Rather than repeat his analysis, I'll just point you at the pdf. It's called [Recurring Events For Calendars](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/recurring.pdf).

Comment: David Skoll has a great presentation on the topic as well, relating to his great tool, remind. http://www.roaringpenguin.com/files/download/remind-oclug.pdf http://www.roaringpenguin.com/products/remind